# Reshaping arrays in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have a binary 3D array of the size 1024 by 1024 by 1024. I want to use a function (`convhull`), which has the following input:

> X is of size mpts-by-ndim, where mpts is the number of points and ndim is the dimension of the space where the points reside, 2 ≦ ndim ≦ 3

How can I reshape my array into the array X which is required by this function?

Maybe "reshape" isn't the best word, because using the "reshape" function isn't enough.

Comment: What does each 3D point in your array represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `convhull` is looking for is a list of subscripts of nonzero elements in your array. Given a 3D array `M`:

```
[X,Y,Z] = ind2sub(size(M), find(M));
```

Then you use these in `convhull`:

```
convhull(X, Y, Z);
```

The lone `X` parameter you mention in your question is just these three column vectors concatenated:

```
X = [X Y Z];
convhull(X);
```